# Redhat 6- Normal user cannot resolve hostname through proxy but root can

Tags: rhel, dns, curl

I have a linux server (in Nutanix) where normal user cannot resolve hostname through proxy but root can, below is the result:

**backup user:**

```
[backup@~]$ curl --insecure --url "https://outlook.office365.com:993/"
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'outlook.office365.com'
```

**root user:**

```
[root@ ~]# curl --insecure --url "https://outlook.office365.com:993/"
* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready.
```

Below is my proxy setting ( all user can read this file):

```
[root@ ~]# env | grep -i proxy
http_proxy=http://10.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/
```

I have checked backup user can read `/etc/resolv.conf` and `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.

What should I check further?

Comment: What adds the proxy setting to root's env? Is it identical for the backup user? If not, it needs to be made for the backup user.

Comment: Hi, yes, is the same setting for backup user, this is root env setting:[backup@ ~]$ cat /etc/environment
http_proxy="http://10.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/"

Comment: Please add to your question the result of the ordinary (backup) user running `env | grep -i proxy`

Comment: Is the server running on SELinux? Run `$ getenforce` lets see

Answer (score 0):

Double check this command `env | grep -i proxy` into the user affected. Remember to add `https_proxy, http_proxy, ftp_proxy and sftp_proxy`. Try to logging in to the user and set them manually. If works, the problem related to the procedure for load the proxy.